# How to keep adding data to next table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This **[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XCfAQ/63/)** shows a comparison table that dynamically shows information in a column when a button is clicked. Once the table is filled up, I want to start the whole process again. But as the example shows, the buttons are stuck at adding information to  `th:nth-child(2)` and `td:nth-child(2)` during the second time instead of moving on to the next column like during the first time.

I'm guessing this part needs some change `if( allCells === fullCells ) {` to keep information being added to next columns.

HTML

```
<div class="area">
    <button>Gah</button>
</div>


<div class="area">
    <button>Kaj</button>
</div>

<div class="area">
    <button>Fdw</button>
</div>

<div class="area">
    <button>ffdf</button>
</div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Placeholder</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Race</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nationality</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Education</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Language</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.area').each(function(){

       var area = $(this),
       filltable ='',
       button = $(this).find('button'),
       buttontext = button.text();    
       button.on("click",function(){

        var allCells = $('table').find('th,td').length;
        var fullCells = $('table').find('th,td').filter(function() { 
         return $(this).text() != ''; 
        }).length;
           if( allCells === fullCells ) { // If table is full
               $('table').find('th,td').not(':first-child').removeClass('addinfo'); 
               filltable();  

              } 
           else { // If table isn't full
                 filltable = function(){  
                 var i = $('th.addinfo').length !== 0 ? $('th.addinfo:last').index() : 0;
                 console.log( i );
                 i + 2 > $('th').length ||
                 $('th,td').filter(':nth-child(' + (i + 2) + ')')
                 .addClass( 'addinfo' ).html(buttontext);
                }
                filltable();
             }
      }); // end button on click function

   }); 

});
```

Comment: What do you exactly want. You have three columns. So once all three columns are filled, then you need to move to first column and replace the data with the new one or you want to add a new column at run time?

Comment: @MohitPandey Once the columns are filled, I want to move to the first column again and replace the data with the new one, so that three of the four sets of data can always be compared all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jqVxu/1/

I think you'd better to count th only. count all td and th make me confused.

```
$(function () {
    function filltable(buttontext) {
        var i = $('th.addinfo').length !== 0 ? $('th.addinfo:last').index() : 0;

        i + 2 > $('th').length || $('th,td').filter(':nth-child(' + (i + 2) + ')')
            .addClass('addinfo').html(buttontext);
    }

    $('.area').each(function () {
        var area = $(this),
            button = $(this).find('button'),
            buttontext = button.text();
        button.on("click", function () {
            var allCells = $('table').find('th').length-1;
            var fullCells = $('table th.addinfo').length;
            console.log(allCells, fullCells);
            if (allCells === fullCells) { // If table is full
                $('table .addinfo').removeClass('addinfo');
                filltable(buttontext);
            } else { // If table isn't full
                filltable(buttontext);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer is better because it doesn't have to clear the old data first before moving back to the first column.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the attached link for demo. I have created a function name cleartable() which clears the table if its full and have used your old filltable() function to repopulate. There is repetition of code which you will have to clean up.

th:nth-child(2) identifies second child of th.
td:nth-child(2) identifies second column.

Similarly if you wanted to do something with let say second row, you can use tr:nth-child(2).

I hope this helps you understand a little about parent-child relationship in jquery.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XCfAQ/65/)

```
function clearTable() {
  $('table th:nth-child(2)').html('');
  $('table th:nth-child(3)').html('');
  $('table th:nth-child(4)').html('');
  $('table td:nth-child(2)').html('');
  $('table td:nth-child(3)').html('');
  $('table td:nth-child(4)').html('');
}
```